# Find out path of the specific font that is used by default by my LaTeX compiler

Tags: fonts

I am aware that `fontforge` can be used to inspect the glyphs of `*.otf` and `*.ttf` files.

I am also aware that the default font used in various document classes is `Computer Modern`.

I want to inspect the specific font that is used by default by my LaTeX compiler. I lack knowledge on how LaTeX handles fonts. By common sense, I thought that somehow LaTeX access the default font whenever I try to compile a simple document, so I created a simple document (see first code block below) and tried to compile it. I used `strace` to list all the files that are read during the compilation process, but the list of files didn't include any file with an extension that looks like a font (see second code block below).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
\end{document}
```

```
$ strace --output=/tmp/main.log --trace=openat pdflatex /tmp/main.tex
$ cat /tmp/main.log
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-config/ls-R", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/ls-R", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/ls-R", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-config", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/babel-2XYaED/main.tex", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/babel-2XYaED/main.tex", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "main.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-config/tex/latex/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-var/tex/latex/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/texmf/tex/latex/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls", O_RDONLY) = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo", O_RDONLY) = 6
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def", O_RDONLY) = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-config/tex/generic/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-var/tex/generic/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/texmf/tex/generic/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-config/tex/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-var/tex/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/texmf/tex/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, "main.aux", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, "main.pdf", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 6
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 7
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-config/fonts/vf/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-var/fonts/vf/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/texmf/fonts/vf/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 7
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-config/fonts/map/pdflatex/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdflatex/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/texmf/fonts/map/pdflatex/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-config/fonts/map/pdftex/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map", O_RDONLY) = 7
openat(AT_FDCWD, "main.aux", O_RDONLY)  = 5
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-config/fonts/type1/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/.texlive2024/texmf-var/fonts/type1/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rodrigo/texmf/fonts/type1/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb", O_RDONLY) = 3
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

My question is: How to find out the specific font in my system that is used when compiling the document and viewing the PDF file?

Comment: The default font used by your LaTeX compiler is shown in the last line of `strace` that you posted above: `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb", O_RDONLY) = 3`. `fontforge` v20201107 is able to open `*.pfb` files. If anyone is aware of other methods for finding the path of the font that is used in a given document, please let me know. I'm curious about this specific topic.

Comment: The paths of all used fonts is in the log file at its end.